# How to use jquery+thickbox open the SubForm, and pass the value to parent form

Tags: jquery, thickbox

like this example:

aa.jsp(parent form)

```
<head> 

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=basePath%>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=basePath%>js/thickbox.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=basePath%>js/thickbox.css">

</head> 
<body> 

    <a href="bb.jsp?TB_iframe=true&placeValuesBeforeTB_=savedValues&height=400&width=170" title="input value" class="thickbox"> 
      <input type="text" name="txtA" id="txtA"/> 
    </a> 

</body>
```

I use the js of jquery and thickbox in the head. And apply them. Click txt textbox to open sub page.

bb.jsp(sub form)：

```
<body> 
  <input type="text" name="txtB" id="txtB"> 
</body>
```

There is one textbox txtB in sub page.

How could I type the context in textbox txtB of bb.jsp, and pass the context to parent page of aa.jsp. Then the context will be diaplayed in textbox txtA in parent page.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, like this:
Import js of thickBox

```
<script src="Upimg/jquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="Upimg/thickbox-compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
class ="thickbox"   Where you want to open the sub form, you can add//
<a href="bb.jsp?TB_iframe=true&amp;height=250&amp;width=400" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox">case 1</a>  
// write js in parent page, like:
function check(id){  
alert(id);  
}
```

The event will be called when opening the bb.jsp page

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function check()
{      
window.parent.check(1);  
}  
</script>  
<body>   
<input type="text" name="txtB" id="txtB" onclick="check();">   
</body>
```